# How to Print List of List of nested classes

Tags: c#, .net, list

I need to print a list of nested class Person. The property Siblings is a list of the Person class. This create an unknown number of depth.

There are a lot of questions and answers up to 3 levels depth. My situation is different.

```
   var Persons= new List<Person>();

         public class Person
            {
                public int ID { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public List<Person> Siblings { get; set; }
            }   


 var Persons = new List<Person>();
            foreach (var prsn in Persons)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prsn.ID);

                foreach (var sibling in prsn.Siblings)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sibling.ID);
                    foreach (var sibling2 in prsn.Siblings)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sibling2.ID);
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt at doing this and we can help you get it working.  Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing site, but we're more than happy to help folks get their code working.

Comment: Can you also provide sample data and expected output please?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem well, this is one of the methods.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
        foreach (Person person in Persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(person.Id);
            if (person.Siblings != null && person.Siblings.Count != 0)
            {
                List<Person> people = GetPersons(person.Siblings);
                foreach (Person person1 in people)
                    Console.WriteLine(person1.Id);
            }
        }
    }

private static List<Person> GetPersons(List<Person> sibling)
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    foreach(Person person in sibling)
    {

        people.Add(person);
        if(person.Siblings != null && person.Siblings.Count!=0)
        {
            List<Person> people1 = GetPersons(person.Siblings);
            people.AddRange(people1);
        }
    }
    return people;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what are you looking for.
But I came up with a piece of code to solve the problem that I think you have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

I made a few changes to your `Person` class

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Siblings = new List<Person>();
        Name = name;
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Siblings { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using the `ForEach()` method I was able to print the list of siblings for each person in the list.

```
var people = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person("Amanda"),
    new Person("Lucas"),
    new Person("George"),
};

var siblings = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person("Mari"),
    new Person("Vini"),
    new Person("Diego"),
};

foreach (var sibling in siblings)
{
    people.ForEach(p => p.Siblings.Add(sibling));
}

foreach (var person in people)
{
    person.Siblings.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine($"{person.Name} has {s.Name} as sibling"));
}
```

The output was:

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The issue is in the Siblings that could go for N generations.

Comment: @Rick How so, do you have an example, or output?

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursion algorithm

```
static void Print(List<Person> Persons)
        {
            if (Persons == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Persons.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Persons[i].ID);

                Print(Persons[i].Siblings);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a simple method to your class that would get all descendant siblings:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var Persons = new List<Person>();
    foreach (var prsn in Persons)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prsn.ID);

        foreach (var sibling in prsn.GetDescendantSibilings())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sibling.ID);
        }

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Siblings { get; set; }

    public List<Person> GetDescendantSibilings()
    {
        var toReturn = new List<Person>(Siblings);
        foreach(var sib in Siblings)
        {
            toReturn.AddRange(sib.GetDescendantSibilings());
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```